# Moving logic to child component from a parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am in situation where a function located in parent component handles onOK for Modal Component, the reason i have located it in parent is due to another local function that gets called once onOk button gets clicked

I would like to move it to child since Modal should be responsible for onOK logic , i can make two components hold visible state or create a stores but the question is how to go about it if another function is involved and that function is glued in parent

Parent

```
  handleModalOk = () => {
            this.onRadioButtonChange(2)
            this.setState({visible: false,});
        };
```

Child

```
<Modal
     title={t('preferenceConfirmTitle')}
     visible={this.props.visible}
     onOk={this.props.onOk}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the function located on the parent to the child. Here's an example:

```
// Parent.js
import React, {useState} from "react";

import Child from "./Child";

const Parent = () => {
    const [myState, setMyState] = useState();

    const funcOnlyInParent = () => {
      console.log("I'm only in the parent");
    }

    const doSomething = (argsFromChild) => {
      setMyState(argsFromChild);

      funcOnlyInParent();
    }
  
   return (
       <div>
          <Child handleDoSomething={doStomething} />
       </div>
   )
}

// Child.js
import React, {useState} from "react";

const Child = (props) => {      
   return (
       <div>
          <button onClick={() => props.handleDoSomething("my arguments")}>Click</button>
       </div>
   )
}
```

The `Child` component will trigger the `doSomething` function in the parent and pass in any arguments that it needs to. Because the function is defined in the `Parent` component, then it can also perform actions on data that only the parent has access to - like setting the parent's state.

Comment: thank you for your effort, I am not trying to pass it to a child i would like child to be responsible for dosomething  => for example parent throws a function to a child as a props, that function should only be called once dosomething is called

Comment: @ArtjomProzorov Let me see if I understand correctly: 1) Child calls `doSomething`, 2) Isolated function in parent is called?

Comment: got it  - >  <PreferenceModal visible={visible}
                                     onRadioChange={this.onRadioButtonChange}/>  and -> handleModalOk = () => {
        this.props.onRadioChange(2);
        this.props.preferenceModalStore.setIsVisible(false)
    };

Comment: Yeh dude, a bit different that you told but you definitely put me on the right track :)

Comment: @ArtjomProzorov Awesome, glad to hear that. Best regards

Answer (score 1):

```
const Parent = () => {

  const function1 = () => {
    // your local code 
  }
  
  return (
    <Modal parentFunction={function1} />
  )
}

const Modal = ({parentFunction}) => {   
  
  const onOK = () => {
    // your local code
    parentFunction()
  }   
   
  return (
    <button onClick={onOK}>Click</button>
   )
}
```